# Do I have to collect my checked luggage if I leave Heathrow during a long layover?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, legal, layovers, lhr

Do I have to collect my checked luggage if I leave Heathrow during a long layover? My agent says the bags are checked through to our final destination, but if we leave the airport, we have to collect them. Is that true? How do the baggage handling service know if we are leaving the airport or not?

Comment: You can always inquiry when checking your bag. And (this may depend on airline/person at counter) you can even have it sent to Heathrow and you can recheck it later.

Answer (score 7):

**No, that's not true**. In fact, if your bags are checked through, it's not even *possible* to collect them since they're going straight to your next plane, not the baggage carousel.

Comment: Yup, and they are also in a secured area that is not accessible from the terminal.

Comment: Well you can ask for them to be delivered to you but this can take more than an hour

Answer (score 3):

No, You don't have to besides, I even wonder how you can even get them. They are redirected to your final destination and there is no such things as taking your bags out whether you have a short or long layover.hope this helps.